# If a series converges does its sequence of partial sums converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, terminology, definition

By Definition, a series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if it's sequence of partial sums $\displaystyle S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ converges.

My question is, is the converse true?
If $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges does it mean $\{S_n\}$ converges?

Comment: Since you said that this is the defintion (and it is) then it's an equivalence!

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane ok but because there is no "if and only if" in the definition I was not sure.

Comment: It is common to simply write "if" in a definition, even though logically one would expect an "iff".

Comment: This is the habit of writing the definitions: we write just "if" and it's in fact " if and only if".

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane ok thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 4):

*This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.*

---

We define convergence of a series as follows:

> The series $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^\infty a_k$ converges **if and only if** its sequence of partial sums $\displaystyle S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k$ converges.

When stating definitions, authors write "if" instead of "if and only if" as mentioned in the comments.